# Add a zero to the returned value if there is no zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following query returns the following sample data from my db.

```
select mobileno
from Person
```

sample results:

```
775623655
0758956556
0756899955
777325656
```

How can I add a 0 in front if there is no 0 in the returned values?

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward to do, did you try anything yet?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Do you want me to show what I tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE LEFT(mobileno,1) 
    WHEN '0' THEN mobileno
    ELSE '0' + isNull(mobileno,'')
    end as mobileno
FROM Person
```

Comment: +1, possibly make it `ELSE '0'+ISNULL(mobileno,'')`

Comment: In theory this is correct as the OP didn't specify that the ID had 10 characters.

Comment: @joao: Have a look at his desired result. It is always filled up to 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
select right('0000000000' + mobileno, 10) mobileno from Person
```

Comment: +1 cause that's my preferred way of doing it ;-)

Comment: The question didn't specify that the column was 10 characters.  What if it was a number that was longer than 10 because of country code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REPLICATE`:

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CAST(mobileno AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) AS mobileno
FROM person;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db520/1)

Answer (score 1):

You want to ensure that it always start with 0 and the length is 10? One way: [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(mobileno, 10, 0), ' ', '0')
FROM dbo.Person
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db520/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

hey check following query . you can do something like that :

```
declare @table table (temp VARCHAR(MAX))

insert into @table values('775623655')
insert into @table values('0758956556')
insert into @table values('0756899955')
insert into @table values('777325656')

SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + temp , 10)
FROM @table
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9b76/2)